# Edit Filter Criteria Option not displayed for View

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Why is the *Edit Filter Criteria* Option not getting displayed for the following view?

[image]

[image]

As you can see above there is no option for updating the filter criteria of this view named *Account BulkOperation View*, while for other views it gets displayed. I am not exactly sure why this is happening or if I am missing something.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks a lot for your post. I have not managed to verify your solution. My access to the CRM is revoked and I will ask the people with access to try your solution. Although I am not sure whether they are allowed to use XrmTool box or not.

Answer (score 1):

Once this happened to me when the view query is customized to an extent with custom fetchxml. Check the background of this view using XrmToolbox FetchXML builder or View designer. Some broken query fields will be there.

> The view is displayed with column layout and possibilities to define sorting and add new columns etc. But there is no link to "Edit Filter Criteria" as there usually is. This is because CRM actually realizes that this view is beyond its design capabilities, and only lets you alter the view in ways CRM knows CRM can handle.

[Read more](https://msdynamicsworld.com/story/create-advanced-views-microsoft-dynamics-crm-using-fetchxml-builder).